# $1$-dimensional reduced local ring $R$ such that $(R:_{Q(R)} \overline R)$ is non-zero and consists of zero-divisors

Tags: commutative-algebra, local-rings, integral-extensions

This question is motivated by [If $(R:_{Q(R) } S)$ is non-zero, then does $(R:_{Q(R) } S)$ contain a non-zero-divisor?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4574140/if-r-qr-s-is-non-zero-then-does-r-qr-s-contain-a-non-zero-d) (and a now deleted comment on it).

Namely: Does there exist a one-dimensional Noetherian reduced local ring $(R,\mathfrak m)$ such that $(R:_{Q(R)} \overline R)$ is non-zero and consists of zero-divisors ?

Here, $\overline R$ denotes the integral closure of $R$ in the total ring of fractions $Q(R)$ of $R$.

Thoughts: Trivially, $R$ cannot be an integral domain. Also, note that if the $\mathfrak m$-adic completion of $R$ is reduced, then $\overline R$ is module finite over $R$ (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/032Y) , hence $(R:_{Q(R)} \overline R)$ contains a non-zero-divisor (namely, a common denominator of a finite generating set of $\overline R$ as $R$-module). Hence any example , if it exists, should have non-reduced completion, in particular $R$ must not be complete.

Comment: If I am understanding $(R:_{Q(R)} \overline{R})$ correctly as the usual conductor ideal, then the answer is no. Since the integral closure localizes, the conductor ideal is $\mathfrak{m}$-primary, so contains a power of $\mathfrak{m}$. Furthermore, since $R$ is reduced, $\text{depth}(R)=1$ so $\mathfrak{m}$ (and hence all its powers) contains a non-zerodivisor. Consequently, $(R:_{Q(R)}\overline{R})$ contains a non-zerodivisor. If $(R:_{Q(R)} \overline{R})$ is something else but is still a height 1 ideal of $R$, the same argument applies.

Comment: @walkar: in general, the conductor may not be $\mathfrak m$-primary, indeed if it were $\mathfrak m$-primary, then the conductor would contain a non-zerodivisor, i.e. The integral closure would be module finite over $R$, and then the completion of $R$ would be reduced (this last part is non-trivial, but well-known, see Leuschke-Wiegand's book) ... in general there are plenty of reduced 1-dimensional rings whose completion is not reduced, however I do not know an example of a 1-dimensional reduced ring with non-zero conductor whose completion is not reduced ...

Comment: Oh, I see -- the issue is that the support of $\overline{R}/R$ may not (does not?) correspond to the set of prime ideals containing its annihilator if $\overline{R}$ is not module-finite. This issue trips me up often! I am used to thinking about the excellent case, for which reduced implies the integral closure is module-finite. Thanks for the correction! I will leave my comments in case someone else makes the same mistake.